# How to add "Read More..." link in twentytwenty

Tags: customization, categories, theme-development, themes

[image]

How do i fix this in twentytwenty so i can show a read more button or something ?

Comment: Is this an archive view or a custom layout? I would suggest investigating the `excerpt_more` filter (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/excerpt_more/) or the more block ( https://gogutenberg.com/blocks/more/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going to the Theme Editor, you can add the following snippet at the end of the ***functions.php*** file:

```
  function twentytwentychild_excerpt_more_add_continue_reading( $more ) {
    return ' [...] <div class="read-more-button-wrap"><a href="' . get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '" class="more-link"><span class="faux-button">Continue reading</span> <span class="screen-reader-text">“' . get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) . '”</span></a></div>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'twentytwentychild_excerpt_more_add_continue_reading' );
```

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/continue-reading-doesnt-appear/

Comment: thank you, works